# How to handle empty session which always gives exception in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Whenever my data in Session is empty it always go into exception, I've to handle this flow using try catch flow,

```
try
{
  Username = Session["Username"].ToString();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  Username = "";
}
```

is there anything from which I can check if session is empty or not.  I think this is not a good way to handle this thing.

Comment: Thought about using Forms Authentication and User.Identity.Name instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calling `ToString` check for `null`

```
try
{
     if(Session["Username"] != null)
         Username = Session["Username"].ToString();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  Username = "";
}
```

You can use [ternary conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) as well and you wont need the `try-catch` block.

```
Username = Session["Username"] == null ? "" Session["Username"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `ToString()` you can use `Convert.ToString()`.

```
string username = Convert.ToString(Session["Username"]);
```

If `Session["Username"]` is null, it will return an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer add a wrapper property for a session.

```
public string Username
{
   get{ if(Session["Username"]!=null) return Session["Username"].ToString() else return String.Empty; }

   set{ Session["Username"] = value; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 try
    {

    if(Session["Username"] != null)
      {
      Username = Session["Username"].ToString();
      }
    }
    else
    {
     //Do Something else
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use string class to check if the string in the session is NULL or not.
you can implement like this.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["Username"]))
{
   //do your stuff
   Username = Session["Username"].ToString();
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
try
{
  if(Session["Username"]!=null)
  {
    Username = Session["Username"].ToString();
  }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  Username = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to avoid null pointer exception you should be using

```
Convert.ToString(Session["Username"]);
```

Rather than

```
Session["Username"].ToString();
```

As Convert.ToString() handles null results also.